# import module with name starting by number followed by underscore

Tags: python

I would like to import a .py into my code.

```py
import 16_module
```

of course this is not working because a module should start by a letter first and additionally here the _ is interpreted as the thousand separator. I guess python see it as an integer **16,**

so I use instead

```py
importlib.import_module('16_module')
```

The import seem working but I cannot call it later on

```py
print(16_module.myfunction())
```

any idea how I could make it work ?

(please don't tell rename the 16_module !!)

Comment: try `import 16_module as mod` something

Answer (score 0):

u can try this:

```
 x = __import__('16_module')
```

Comment: thx @Jax.ajay !
any ideas how to limit the import for one [or few functions] ?
like with: from MyFile import function1

Comment: i didnt get u SpongeBOB

Comment: as stack overflow lack of msg between user -> https://imgur.com/ct931Ng

Comment: it appear that solution only import functions from the module. but not the rest (variable, list etc.. :/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
new_name = importlib.import_module('16_module')
```

Then you can use:

```
new_name.myfunction()
```